# Cannot install JDK 7 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: macos, java

I tried to install JDK 7u67 on my MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra 10.12.6, but all I get is this error message:

[image: Java from Oracle requires Mac OS X 10.7.3 or later.]

It does not really makes sense for me, because I already have higher version, so Java should be able to install. Has anyone faced same issue, please?

Answer (score 5):

Similar to what @[klanomath](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath) suggests:

1. Copy the pkg off the disk image so it can be edited.
2. Extract pkg contents in Terminal (assumes "JDK 7 Update 67.pkg" is your pkg name): `pkgutil --expand JDK\ 7\ Update\ 67.pkg JDK\ 7\ Update\ 67.unpkg`
3. Edit the Distribution file with your favorite text editor.
4. Change the return value of pm_install_check() to always be true.

```
    function pm_install_check() {
      return true;
    }
```

5. Save the Distribution file.
6. Back in Terminal: `pkgutil --flatten  JDK\ 7\ Update\ 67.unpkg JDK\ 7\ Update\ 67.new.pkg`
7. Run/Open the new pkg file.

Answer (score 3):

The check is performed by the `pm_install_check()` function in the package's Distribution.

1. Copy the pkg off the disk image so it can be edited
2. Open it with [The Archive Browser](https://theunarchiver.com/archive-browser)
3. Edit the Distribution file with TextEdit (right-click on Distribution and choose Open With to edit the file in place).
4. Remove the following lines so the function always returns true.

   [image]
5. Save the file and open the pkg.

Comment: The Archive browser cannot open *.dmg file

Comment: @Jakub You need to open the pkg with The Archive Browser, that’s why I suggest copying it off the dmg.

Comment: I am trying to install java7 u67 on a 10.12.6 system and, after I modify the Distribution script as above, I see an error. In the install.log, it says:

Comment: NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=BOMCopierFatalError Code=1 \"cpio read error: bad file format\" UserInfo={destinationPath=/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/95987656-1AAB-4B6C-A504-17D2545380A5.activeSandbox/Scripts/com.oracle.jre.ROFBey, offset=50831541, type=BOMCopierFatalError, sourcePath=/Users/rakiddy/Java 7 Update 67.pkg, NSLocalizedFailureReason=cpio read error: bad file format}";

Answer (score 1):

This is an obvious thing to happen, cause JDK 7 was made for previous versions of macOS. You need to use JDK 8 in order to successfully install it on your current macOS version.
Check Here: [Java SE Development Kit 8 Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: Is there any solution to install JDK 7 anyway? We have application that is based on JDK 7 and because of its dependencies, it is not so simple to switch to JDK 8.

Comment: Switching to JDK 8 is very easy for your application there is a JVM in your machine(not necessarily JDK-8).

Android by default installs a JVM in your computer. Open a project in Android studio,

Goto File -> Project Structure -> SDK location

There you can see, default JDK location, if there is no such thing then,

1.install JDK-8, and Set the Environmental variables.

2.Set the jdk path in the JDK location in the android studio.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to insist on JDK 7.

Comment: @JakubGruber check here: https://pastebin.com/SvGPzaTH . This might help